# Unable to pass parameter to stored procedure

Tags: mysql

My requirement to calculate sum of day, month and year amounts. I written the stored procedure as below.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`ntc`@`%` PROCEDURE `AgentRank`(IN Agentid int)

BEGIN
    select (select  @DayAmount := sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday from 
        collection_master  
        where  AgentID=Agentid and  day(Date_Time)= day(CURRENT_DATE()) 
        group by AgentID
    ) as Dayamount,

    (select  @MonthAmount :=sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday  from 
        collection_master
        where  AgentID=Agentid and date_time between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') and LAST_DAY(now() - interval 0 month )
        group by AgentID
    ) as monthamount,

    (select   @YearAmount := sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountpermonth  from 
        collection_master  
        where AgentID=Agentid  and year(Date_Time) =YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
        group by AgentID
    ) as yearamount,

    (select @Position := @Position + 1 AS Rank  from 
        collection_master ,(SELECT @Position := 0) r
        where AgentID=Agentid
        group by AgentID
    ) as position;

END
```

When I am executing the stored procedure I am getting below output[image]

When I am executing in individual query of store procedure I am getting correct output as below[image]

Please check it once and where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first few lines of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ntc`@`%` PROCEDURE `AgentRank`(IN Agentid int)
BEGIN
    select (select  @DayAmount := sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday
            from collection_master  
            where  AgentID=Agentid and  day(Date_Time)= day(CURRENT_DATE()) 
-------------------^
            group by AgentID
           ) as Dayamount,
```

The pointed-to expression is a *tautology*.  That is, it is comparing the column `AgentId` to itself.  The problem is that your parameter has the same name as the column, a bad, bad, bad, bad idea.  Here is a fix:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ntc`@`%` PROCEDURE `AgentRank`(IN v_Agentid int)
BEGIN
    select (select  @DayAmount := sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday
            from collection_master  
            where AgentID = v_Agentid and day(Date_Time)= day(CURRENT_DATE()) 
           ) as Dayamount,
```

Also note that you do not need the aggregation.  The subquery has to return zero or one rows (or you get an error).  You are selecting only one `AgentId`, so remove the `group by` to prevent misinterpretation.

Comment: one more suggestion how to give rank based on sum(dayamount)+sum(monthamount)+sum(yearaamount) where agent=v_agent than rank=?

Comment: @sandeep . . . That sounds like a very different question.  Ask another question along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: yes gordon    i asked here please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602987/ranking-applied-over-multiple-columns-in-mysql-using-stored-procedure